# How can I check list with numbers, that is ordered numerically in Robot Framework

Tags: sorting, robotframework

I have problem with checking my list. Actually I need check that list is ordered numerically in Robot Framework.

Let's imagine that we have a list

```
${nice}= ['13', '12', '10', '7', '6', '6', '6', '4', '3', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0']
```

I need to verify that the first element is greater than the second, the second greater than the third and so on.

Problem is, that in Robot Framework keyword 'Sort List' doesn't order number list in proper way.

One of the decision is to call Python method 'sort' or 'sorted' in robot framework, but maybe there is better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sort List** keyword sorts lists as strings so it puts `11` before `2` for example.

If you have to check if a list is ordered numerically, you can do that without sorting. You should simply iterate the list and compare adjacent elements to each other. For example:

```
*** Variables ***
@{LIST_NOK}     13    12    10    7    6    6    6    4    3    2    2    1    1    1    0    0
@{LIST_OK}     999    765    213     78    21    12   2

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Check List    ${LIST_OK}
    Check List    ${LIST_NOK}
    
    
*** Keywords ***
Check List
    [arguments]    ${list}
    ${length}=    Get Length    ${list}
    FOR     ${i}    IN RANGE    ${length-1}
        ${first}=    Set Variable    ${list}[${i}]    # element at index i in ${list}
        ${second}=   Set Variable    ${list}[${i+1}]  # element at index i+1 in ${list}
        Run Keyword If    ${first} <= ${second}    Fail    Element ${first} is not greater than ${second}.
    END
```

If you do not like seeing these `${list}[${i+1}]`, so [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) in use, you should go with Python. Either via the Evaluate keyword or via some small test library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's `sorted` using `Evaluate` keyword to get the list elements in descending order and then use `Lists Should Be Equal` keyword to compare them

```
Import Library     Collections
@{nice}=    Create List    13    12    10    7    6    6    6    4    3    2    2    1    1    1    0    0                                              
${sorted}=    Evaluate     sorted(${nice}, key=int, reverse=True)                                                                                       
Lists Should Be Equal    ${nice}    ${sorted}
```

Comment: Great, nice advice