# How to check given list is sorting order or not in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

Input Data = [(1234)Test, 12344, 1stel, Inc, Xcom]

My input data has string with number and brackets. How could I check this input list has sorted or not?

```
    *** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    Collections
*** Test Cases ***
Check sorting order
        @{list}=    Create List     (1234)Test      (3455)Testing     (BMA) Billiton Mitsubishi Coal    12344    180 SQUARED, INC.
        ${sorted_list}=    sort list     ${list}
        log    ${sorted_list}
```

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63620576/3820025

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check list with numbers, that is ordered numerically in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598557/how-can-i-check-list-with-numbers-that-is-ordered-numerically-in-robot-framewor)

Comment: Not working: No keyword with name 'Sort List Custom' found.

Comment: You know that we do not see your code, right?